# iframe formatting removed on form re-submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

Thanks in advance. I'm rather new to this so please bear with me.

I have a form that gets submitted to a server and a response is generated. When the response is delivered back to the user, it gets redirected to an iFrame. The first submit and response work fine, the response format is in an xml type format. Response example in iFrame:

```
< Values><br>
  < value1>1< /value1><br>
  < value2>1< /value2><br>
  < value3>11< /value3><br>
< /Values>
```

When a user submits the form again (regardless of any changes), the xml formatting gets removed and the response is an indeterminable string of numbers.
Second response example in iFrame:

```
1111
```

We need to have the users get a response in the xml format to verify data every time, not just the first.  To paint the picture a bit, this is all HTML and Javascript, the form submission page is part of a frameset. The response goes to an iframe in another frame within the same frameset.

[Visual webpage representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0sF6.png)

I'll post whatever code is requested.

Comment: this is the response iframe code ` <iframe name="formresponse" width="500" height="300" id="formresponse"></iframe>`

Comment: `function HandlePostBack(form) { form.action = document.getElementById("TRXNSrvr").value; d = document.getElementById("TRXNSrvr").value; if (d == 0) { alert("Please select a server to process this transaction!"); } else { document.forms['form51'].target = 'formresponse'; form.submit(); } }` @Aks

Answer (score 0):

Could you then post the JS where you redirect your reponse to the iFrame ?
(NB : If you have some logs, that may help)

Comment: function HandlePostBack(form) {
            form.action = document.getElementById("TRXNSrvr").value;            
            d = document.getElementById("TRXNSrvr").value;
            if (d == 0) {
                alert("Please select a server to process this transaction!");
            }
            else {
                document.forms['form51'].target = 'formresponse';
                form.submit();
            }
        }

Comment: Ok, that'll not help that much.  xD

Could you consider using console.log() in your code and test it, so we will have few informations. In other case, we will need more of your code

Comment: For the record, this is still testing and not in production. We use IE and are on version 11.  In Network details response body of the debugger console within IE (F12), i see the xml format is being sent back correctly on the second and further responses.

Comment: In Console, this is the only message I get after a submit:  "DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337"